# Select a cell in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I'm having a table structure: -

```
<div class="nli fshout_nli">
<table>
    <tr class="a_cell corner-all">
        <td valign="top">
            <a href="auser.jsp?id=1"><img src="dir/image_19.jpeg" alt="image"/></a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" height="50px">
            <div class="on_text bl_txt">Pradyut Bhattacharya shouted</div>
            <div class="text bl_txt">

                this is a new test... <br/> <br/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">

            Z <br /> M
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="on_text bl_txt1">
                on <span class="timestamp"> 8:52 PM Sunday Jan 30, '11 </span>

                with <a href="#" class="show_comment1 green_link" >2 comments</a>
                <a href="#" class="ushout green_link" >Shouts</a>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now I'm selecting the table using the code:

```
 $(this).parents('.nli').children('table').text()
```

I want to select the first tr's first td or

table > tr(0) > td(0)

How can I do so using my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow your code, but you can get the first `td` element of the closest parent table using the following code:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('td:first');
```

This uses [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to get the nearest parent element matching a selector and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to get a child element matching a selector, using the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector) selector to get the first element matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents('.nli').find('td:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (from the table)

```
$(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
```

Comment: the answer should be $(this).parents('.nli').find("td").eq(0).html() ... any solution without find...:D

Answer (score 0):

$(this).parents('.nli').children('table tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text()